# How to create PNR on SABRE with passenger details

Tags: sabre

Can anyone please provide perfect steps to create PNR on sabre from session create till PNR and session close. I also need WSDL URLs for these steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ + TravelItineraryReadRQ + EndTransaction can be summarized in a single step by calling PassengerDetailsRQ

Comment: Will this store fare automatically to the newly generated PNR ? If yes than how can I re-validate stored fare on PNR ?

Comment: You can do that with EnhancedAirBook.

Comment: <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">  "Retain" is used to instruct the system to retain the pricing response and create a price quote record.  this will retain the fare. after creating PNR read it with TravelItineraryReadRQ and you can check if its response has the fare details.

Comment: What about the new com.sabre.redapp.example.pnr Sample: it's supposed to access the PNR when there is one in the workspace. This is documented in the help of Sabre SDK 3.2 RC1, but the sample is not provided. Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

## Steps for Create PNR in sabre System

setp1. OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ

setp2. EnhancedAirBookRQ

step3. TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ ( add passenger details)

step4. TravelItineraryReadRQ (Confirm Passenger Details)

step5. EndTransactionRQ

Note: this Steps should have same sessions. After EndTransactionRQ you will get PNR

## More Details use following link

https://developer.sabre.com/

Comment: Will this store fare automatically to the newly generated PNR ? If yes than how can I re-validate stored fare on PNR ?

Comment: <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true"> Price Retain will work for PQ Enabled Client only, otherwise It will show  error like 'TJR'